# Saving dynamically created buttons on firebase from kivy

Tags: python, firebase, kivy, kivymd

I'm making an app that can dynamically create new buttons that in turn lead to other screens. What I am trying now, is to save this progress in firebase so that when I launch my app again, the buttons are already present on the screen, unless I dynamically delete them. How can I do this?

Comment: maybe first try to create code which get all information as dictionary - and write information in normal file - text, csv, json, sqlite. And later try to write it with firebase. And in both version you will have to create code to which recreate object using dictionary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.